# How do you maintain the manual setup of Drupal installation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, drupal, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set up an elastic beanstalk deployment of Drupal to host a Drupal built website.

When I start up my ec2 instance, I go through the installation steps of setting up Drupal.

[image]

However, when the instance is Restarted, or Stopped, restarting the instance goes back to this page!

How can I configure the instance so that these installation steps do not need to be repeated even when the instance goes down.  This is quite worrying as I am looking to host my website this way.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This step means that drupal can't find database or it can find it but installation is not done yet (required tables are not created). So if you pass installation and you see again this screen it can mean 2 things:

1. Your database configuration is lost, so drupal can't find DB.
2. DB configuration file is ok, but DB it self is lost so configuration must be done again.

So first check what is the problem in your case and then solve it. Probably since you are installing in instance, DB configuration is then recorded and then lost when your box expires. If so...find a way to make permanent change do config file (should be `/sites/default/settings.php`).